# Docker registry mirror not used

Tags: docker

When I try to pull an image from my local mirror, it works :

```
$ docker login -u docker -p mypassword nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000
$ docker pull nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000/hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from **hello-world**
78445dd45222: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:c5515758d4c5e1e838e9cd307f6c6a0d620b5e07e6f927b07d05f6d12a1ac8d7
Status: Downloaded newer image for **nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000/hello-world:latest**
```

But then, when I want to use this registry as mirror, it is just ignored, images are always pulled from web Docker hub, not from my local mirror :

```
$ ps -ef | grep docker
/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --storage-driver=overlay2 --registry-mirror=https://nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000

$ docker info
Registry Mirrors:
 https://nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000/

$ docker rmi nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000/hello-world
```

_

```
$ docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from **library/hello-world**
78445dd45222: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:c5515758d4c5e1e838e9cd307f6c6a0d620b5e07e6f927b07d05f6d12a1ac8d7
Status: Downloaded newer image for **hello-world:latest**
```

I know for sure it doesn't use my mirror, because when I unset the proxy settings, it cannot reach hello-world image.

Is it a Docker bug, or am I missing something ?

Docker info (short) :

```
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
(...)
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.8.0-37-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.10
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 15.67 GiB
(...)
Registry Mirrors:
 https://nexus3.pleiade.edf.fr:5000/
```

**UPDATE** :

Doing "journalctl -xe", I can see some useful information :

`level=error msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get https://nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials"`

It looks related to : https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20097, but the workaround is not working : when I replace --registry-mirror=https://nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000 by --registry-mirror=https://docker:password@nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000

I get exactly the same error.

If it matters, the nexus is using a self signed certificate which has been copied to /etc/docker/certs.d/nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000/ca.crt and this allowed to login via "docker login".

Comment: Is `https://nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000` internally hosted? If yes, then try adding a `no_proxy=nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr`

Comment: I've already tried with no proxy at all. And the error wouldn't be "Get https://nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials" if there was a proxy problem.

Comment: Probably one more docker bug on a main feature : https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/30880. The workaround is to set up a https reverse proxy setting a hard-coded authentication header.

Comment: Sorry to ping an old thread but in case someone else makes my mistake, ensure that docker-registries isn't declared twice in your daemon.json. =/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a docker bug : https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/30880

The workaround is to set up a https reverse proxy setting a hard-coded authentication header.

Here is an example config from [Felipe C.](https://github.com/phlbrz) :

In nginx docker config, add :

```
proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic a2luZzppc25ha2Vk";
```

Full example:

```
server {
    listen *:443 ssl http2;
    server_name docker.domain.blah.net;
    ssl on;
    include ssl/domain.blah.net.conf;
    # allow large uploads of files - refer to nginx documentation
    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=";

        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
    }
}

server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name docker.domain.blah.net;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Newest Nexus versions support things like "Docker Barer Token Realm", so this workaround should work, but probably there is other solutions. Of course, there are other alternatives like use Kubernetes or OpenShift that allow to specify private registries as 'default registries'. It depends of the use case.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me to add a /etc/docker/daemon.json:

```
{
    "registry-mirrors": [ "nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr" ],
    "max-concurrent-downloads": 20
}
```

Comment: It's interesting but you should tell us much more (which OS, which docker version, ...). On my OS (Ubuntu) I can't use /etc/docker/daemon.json to customize the systemd service.

Comment: this solution can't possibly work, since it's the same setup for which the issue has been reported... and I am using it and still have the "no basic auth credentials" issue. It seems that the nginx solution is currently the only viable workaround - sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is docker logout other servers.
And enable the registry config Allow anonymous docker pull ( Docker Bearer Token Realm required ).

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party but i hope this helps someone. I was facing the same issue and getting the auth error in nexus logs.

It turns out I had to enable anonymous docker pull in my nexus repository settings

[image]

Also after doing so check under Security->Realms that `Docker Bearer Token Realm` is active and given high priority

[image]

Comment: I tried allow all of anonymouse docker pull, but still not work.

Answer (score -5):

You can add basic auth in URL and it works for me. Something like

```
https://username:password@nexus3.pleiade.mycomp.fr:5000
```

Comment: Docker doesnt allow this it complains with `invalid mirror: username/password not allowed in URI`

Comment: this should be forbidden and punished by w3c, username and password plain in URL  *shakes head*